# Computing the characteristic function of a Rice Random Variable

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, contour-integration, fourier-transform

So I want to solve the following integral:

$$\varphi(t) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{ x }{\sigma^{2}} e^{ \frac{-(x^{2} + v^{2})}{2 \sigma^{2}}  } I_{0} \left( \frac{xv}{\sigma^{2}}   \right) e^{jxt} dx$$

where $I_{0}(\cdot)$ is the modified Bessel function and $j$ is the imaginary unity.

To start, we bring out the exponential and expand the modified Bessel function:

$$\varphi(t) = \frac{1}{\sigma^{2}} e^{\frac{-v^{2}}{2 \sigma^{2}}} \int_{0}^{\infty} x e^{ -\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}} I_{0} \left( \frac{xv}{\sigma^2} \right) e^{jxt} dx $$

$$\varphi(t) = \frac{1}{\sigma^{2}} e^{\frac{-v^{2}}{2 \sigma^{2}}} \int_{0}^{\infty} x e^{ -\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{ \left(  \frac{xv}{2 \sigma^2}\right)^{2k}}{k! \Gamma(k+1)} e^{jxt} dx $$

$$\varphi(t) = \frac{1}{\sigma^{2}} e^{\frac{-v^{2}}{2 \sigma^{2}}} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{ \left(  \frac{v}{2 \sigma^2}\right)^{2k}}{k! \Gamma(k+1)} \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{2k+1} e^{ -\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}  e^{jxt} dx $$

$$\varphi(t) = \frac{1}{\sigma^{2}} e^{\frac{-v^{2}}{2 \sigma^{2}}} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{ \left(  \frac{v}{2 \sigma^2}\right)^{2k}}{k! \Gamma(k+1)} \varphi_{1}(\infty) $$

So we focus on $\varphi_{1}(\infty)$. We let $u = jx$ such that $j^{-1}du = dx$. Noticing that $j^{-n} = 1$ when $n$ is even, we have:

Thus:

$$\varphi_{1}(\infty) = \int_{0}^{j \infty} u^{2k+1} e^{\frac{1}{2 \sigma^2} u^2 - tu} du $$

If we complete the square, we get:

$$\varphi_{1}(\infty) = e^{-\frac{1}{2} t^{2} \sigma^2}\int_{0}^{j \infty} u^{2k+1} e^{\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} (u-\sigma^2 t)^2} du $$

Now we can expand the exponential function:

$$e^{\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} (u-\sigma^2 t)^2}  = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(u-\sigma^2 t)^{2n}}{n!}
 $$

We can use the binomial theorem to expand $(u-\sigma^2 t)^{2n}$ but I think then we end up with more sums than we really need.

So this is where I am stuck. I probably went wrong where I let $u=jx$ but I don't know what else I should do...

Any help?

---

By the way, the answer can be found here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice_distribution#cite_note-2

And is:

$$ I(t) = e^{\frac{-v^{2}}{2 \sigma^{2}}}  \left[ \Psi_{2}\left( 1; 1; \frac{1}{2}; \frac{v^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}, -\frac{1}{2} \sigma^{2} t^{2} \right) +  j \sqrt{2} \sigma t \Psi_{2} \left( \frac{3}{2}; 1; \frac{3}{2}; \frac{v^{2}}{2 \sigma^{2}}; -\frac{1}{2} \sigma^{2}t^{2} 
 \right) \right]$$

where:

$$ \Psi_{2} \left( \alpha; \beta; \gamma; x; y  \right) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{ (\alpha)_{m+n} }{(\beta)_{m} (\gamma)_{n}} \frac{x^{m}y^{n}}{m!n!}  $$

and

$$ (\alpha)_{n} = \alpha (\alpha + 1) (\alpha+2) \ldots (\alpha + n-1) $$

is the rising factorial.

Although, a simpler answer would be better!

---

According to Mathematica:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{2 k+1} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2 s^2}+i t x} dx = 2^k s^{2 k+2} \left(\Gamma (k+1) \, _1F_1\left(k+1;\frac{1}{2};-\frac{1}{2} s^2 t^2\right)+i \sqrt{2} s t \Gamma \left(k+\frac{3}{2}\right) \,
   _1F_1\left(k+\frac{3}{2};\frac{3}{2};-\frac{1}{2} s^2 t^2\right)\right) $$

So I know I am on the right track...just...how do I get these Hypergeometric functions out of there? And how do I get the imaginary unit out of the exponent?

---

Okay so a bit of progress. We let $u = \frac{x^{2}}{2s^{2}}$. This gives us:

$$ 2^{k}s^{2k+2} \left( \int_{0}^{\infty} u^k e^{-u}e^{j \sqrt{2 s^{2}u}t} du \right) = 2^{k} s^{2 k+2} \left( \left(\Gamma (k+1) \, _1F_1\left(k+1;\frac{1}{2};-\frac{1}{2} s^2 t^2\right)+i \sqrt{2} s t \Gamma \left(k+\frac{3}{2}\right) \,
   _1F_1\left(k+\frac{3}{2};\frac{3}{2};-\frac{1}{2} s^2 t^2\right)\right) \right)$$

Now we split up the complex exponential: $e^{j \sqrt{2 s^{2} u} t} = cos(\sqrt{2 s^{2} u} t) + jsin(\sqrt{2 s^{2} u} t)$. This give us:

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} u^k e^{-u} e^{ \sqrt{2 s^{2}u}t} du = \int_{0}^{\infty} u^k e^{-u}cos( \sqrt{2 s^{2}u}t) du + 1j\int_{0}^{\infty} u^k e^{-u}sin(\sqrt{2 s^{2}u}t) du  $$

But now I am having trouble reducing both sides to the Hypergeometric function. Mathematica does it for me, but how do I do it myself?

---

Thanks!

Comment: Try expanding $\sin$ and $\cos$ as a Taylor series and you can pull the sum outside the integral via dominated convergence. You'll then get a sum of gamma functions upon integration, which should reduce to a hypergeometric function.

Comment: @AlexR. Yes that is exactly what I did, however I am tripping up in reducing all the factorials / gamma functions. I would really like to know how to do this.

Comment: @AlexR. Specifically, where does that (1/2) come from? Evaluating the Pochhammer symbol in the Hypergeometric gives me $\sqrt{\pi}$, what? Haha so confused!